# Error on doctrine create database with docker-compose

Tags: php, docker, symfony, docker-compose

I have a problem. When I try to create a database from Dockerfile, I got an error :

> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112:
>
> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
> php_network_getaddr   esses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in
> name resolution
>
> In Exception.php line 18:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
> Tempor   ary failure in name resolution
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 38:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
> Tempor   ary failure in name resolution
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 38:
>
> PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
> Temporary    failure in name resolution
>
> doctrine:database:create [-s|--shard SHARD] [-c|--connection
> [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists]
>
> ERROR: Service 'www' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c php
> bin/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists' returned a
> non-zero code: 1

**project structure :**

```
project
    bin/
    config/
    src/
    docker/
        apache/
            vhost.conf
        php/
            Dockerfile
    src/
    docker-compose.yml
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
    db:
        image: mariadb
        container_name: db_app
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - app-db:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
        ports:
            - 1212:3306
        expose:
            - 1212
        networks:
            - dev

    www:
        depends_on:
            - db
        container_name: www_app
        ports:
            - 8686:80
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
        restart: always
        networks:
            - dev

networks:
    dev:

volumes:
    app-db:
```

In my .env file:

> DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:pass@**db_app**:3306/super-app"

**Dockerfile** :

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev g++ git libicu-dev zip libzip-dev zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl opcache pdo pdo_mysql \
    && pecl install apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip

# source + conf apache
COPY . /var/www
COPY ./docker/apache/vhosts.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

WORKDIR /var/www

# Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN composer install --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-interaction

# doctrine
RUN php bin/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists
```

If I don't write this line: "**RUN php bin/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists**", docker is ok and I can enter in my container and type mannually this command, but I want to do this in my Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that RUN commands in your Dockerfile are executed at the time of the `www` image build, which happens *before* either of the containers are launched and networked by docker-compose. What you want to utilise is CMD, which is the command the container executes when you launch the built image. A typical way to do this could be to create an init shell script to call from the Dockerfile and put any start-up commands you need in it.

Create this in `docker/php/init.sh` and `chmod 744` to make it executable:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

bin/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists
apache2-foreground
```

Then in your Dockerfile replace:

```
# doctrine
RUN php bin/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists
```

With:

```
# init
CMD ["/var/www/docker/php/init.sh"]
```

See this article for further details about the differences between RUN and CMD - https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd/

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's ok !